# Python Paramiko/SSH error

Tags: python, ssh

I'm new to Python and learning SSH usage. Could someone help me in identifying the cause of the errors. Basically trying to connect to a device via ssh from a Unix box and execute a simple 'show version' command and return/print its output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ssh.py", line 33, in <module>
ver = node.cmd('show version')
File "/home/xxxx/python/classes/ssh.py", line 17, in cmd
stdin, stdout, stderr = self.node.exec_command(command)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 345, in exec_command
chan.exec_command(command)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 60, in _check
return func(self, *args, **kwds)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 229, in exec_command
self._wait_for_event()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1086, in _wait_for_event
raise e
EOFError
```

The debug

```
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.455] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x23f2310L
INF [20161107-17:37:31.460] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_3.5p1)
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.463] thr=1   paramiko.transport: blah blah
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.463] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-cbc, remote=aes128-cbc
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.463] thr=1   paramiko.transport: blah blah
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.466] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Got server p (1024 bits)
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.610] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.627] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-rsa host key for as102.lnstb: xxxxxxxxxxx
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.633] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20161107-17:37:31.669] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (password) successful!
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.693] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.696] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.696] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEB [20161107-17:37:31.704] thr=1   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
```

The code

```
class Ssh:

def connect(self, host, user, password):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username = user, password = password)
    self.node = ssh

def cmd(self,command):
     stdin, stdout, stderr = self.node.exec_command(command)
     return stdout.read()

node = Ssh()
node.connect(host,user,pwd)
ver = node.cmd('show version')
print(ver)
```

Answer (score 0):

So i tried this on another device which is provided by a seperate vendor and it works.. Seems this specific vendor needs some tweaking with in the paramiko config.